# Filling XML Path columns

Tags: sql-server

```
    Declare @SQL varchar(max) = 'Select NOM_EMP as [X],PRENOM_EMP as [Y],'
+ (Select Stuff((Select ',[' +cast(N as varchar(25))+']=''''' 
                From (Select Top (31) N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select null)) From master..spt_values n1) A
                For XML Path 
                (''))
                ,1,1,'')
   )
+ ' FROM EMPLOYE'

Exec(@SQL)
```

What I'm doing here is loading employees names + number of days in the current month (31 in this case). The above query will result in something like this:

[image]

The employe table is related `(EMPLOYE_ID)` to ,say `Requests` table, each request have a `start_date` and `end_date`.

What I want to achieve is to have the letter "R" written If `start_date` and `end_date` day number matches the day number in the cell.

If a request is made (by the first employe) with this info: **08-10-2018** and
**08-14-2018**

The table should look like this:

[image]

Is that something realistic to achieve? If so, any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

```
    Declare @D1 datetime = '2018-08-01'
Declare @D2 datetime = '2018-08-31'


Declare @Cols varchar(max) = (Select Stuff((Select ',[' +cast(N as varchar(25))+']' From (Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,@D1,@D2)+1) N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)) From  master..spt_values n1) A For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') )
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Declare @D1 date = '''+cast(@D1 as varchar(50))+'''
Declare @D2 date = '''+cast(@D2 as varchar(50))+'''

Select *
 From  ( 
        Select firstName,LastName,
              Item      = day(d)
              ,Value     = case when D between DEBUT_DRC and FIN_DRC then ''R'' else '''' end
         From DEMANDE_RECUPERATION DC INNER JOIN EMPLOYE E ON DC.MAT_EMP = E.MAT_EMP 
         Cross Join (
                        Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,@D1,@D2)+1) D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),@D1) From  master..spt_values n1
                    ) B
       ) src
 Pivot (max(value) for Item in ('+@Cols+') ) pvt
'
Exec(@SQL)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by expanding your dynamic SQL a bit

**Example**

```
Declare @D1 date = '2018-08-01'
Declare @D2 date = '2018-08-31'


Declare @Cols varchar(max) = (Select Stuff((Select ',[' +cast(N as varchar(25))+']' From (Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,@D1,@D2)+1) N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)) From  master..spt_values n1) A For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') )
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Declare @D1 date = '''+cast(@D1 as varchar(50))+'''
Declare @D2 date = '''+cast(@D2 as varchar(50))+'''

Select *
 From  ( 
        Select A.Employee
              ,Item      = day(d)
              ,Value     = case when D between start_date and end_date then ''R'' else '''' end
         From YourRequestTable A
         Cross Join (
                        Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,@D1,@D2)+1) D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),@D1) From  master..spt_values n1
                    ) B
       ) src
 Pivot (max(value) for Item in ('+@Cols+') ) pvt
'
Exec(@SQL)
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: It's not returning anything. I thought first it was my inner join but I tried to retrieve teh EmployeID since I have names in another table, but that didn't do anything. It's still returning an empty table

Comment: @Zkai You never posted your actual structures, but here is a dbfiddle  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=9730906516599d61653b18db7cc78615

Comment: I posted my working. No errors are being returned, and the returned table is empty. Is it possible that because I'm using Datetime instead of date? but I doubt it.

Comment: @Zkai for starters,  variable D1 and D2 datetime should be DATE not datetime.   If you run the sub-query "src" do you get data ...  you'll have to declare the variables D1 and D2

Comment: @Zkai Rather than Exec({at}SQL)  Print {at}SQL, this will produce the generated SQL.  Perhaps that will reveal the issue.  I suspect your join

Comment: Nevermind. I was running the query in "Master" database, I forgot to select my database and that why It wasn't returning anything.

Comment: @Zkai It is always the small things  :)

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for taking time and answering me by the way, I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

more or less:

```
WITH cteDates AS ( SELECT [calDt] = @dtStart
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT [CalDt] = DATEADD(DAY, [calDt], 1) FROM cteDates WHERE [calDt] <= @dtEnd)
SELECT pvt.*
  FROM ( SELECT e.EmployeeID, d.[calDt], [reqCount] = COUNT(*)
           FROM cteDates d
          CROSS JOIN Employee e
           LEFT JOIN reqTable rt ON rt.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
                                AND rt.d1 >= d.[cteDt]
                                AND rt.d2 <= d.[cteDt]
         GROUP BY e.EmployeeID, d.[calDt]
       ) unpvt
 PIVOT ( SUM(reqCount) FOR [calDt] IN ( [1],[2],...[31] )
       ) AS pvt
```

no dynamic SQL necessary